Question on the expected number of same color balls left in a urn
I'm working on a problem where I am given an urn with $a$ white balls and $b$ black balls. One ball at a time is selected randomly until there is only balls of the same color. I am asked to find the expected number of balls left in the urn when the experiment ends, $M_{a, b}$. I am also told that such formula is recursive.
I think that I can express $M_{a, b}$ in terms of $M_{a-1, b}$ and $M_{a, b-1}$ using the proportion of white balls to black balls. Without loss of generality, suppose $a > b$. I think $M_{a, b}$ can be regarded as the weighted average of $M_{a-1, b}$ and $M_{a, b-1}$ as it is more likely to $M_{a, b}$ to be closer to $M_{a-1, b}$ given $a > b$. My idea would be something like this:
$$
M_{a, b} = \frac{a}{a + b}M_{a-1, b} + \frac{b}{a + b}M_{a, b_1}.
$$
Does this make sense? I have no other idea of how this problem could be approached.

Yes, the formula looks good. I think the problem is equivalent to the "problem of points". You'll find info about the solution there. The solution will involve sums of binomial coefficients.

I suggest:  condition on the last color in the urn.  Given that, work out the expected location (from the end) of the first instance of the other color.

Note
Although in my solution I used linearity of expectation (which I'm biased towards), an alternative solution by recursion/induction, as originally asked for, is available at this link on Cross Validated. The key observation is the same, but the method of calculation is different.
Hint
Consider all permutations of all $a+b$ balls. If draw the balls in this order, this permutation uniquely determines the way you select (take some time to internalize why this is true). Since you stop early, the number of contiguous balls of the same color at the very end of this sequence are the number of balls left in the urn.
Full Solution

 Employing the hint, we can reverse the sequence. We want to find the expected number of balls of the same color we will draw when starting out, picking according to this new sequence. Reversing a sequence is a bijection between the set of permutations and itself, so the expected value will still be the same.


 Now, we could use recursion, but I believe linearity of expectation gets to the answer a bit faster, without needing to experiment to arrive at an answer form (albeit a little less intuitively). Let us first take the case where the sequence starts with a black ball. This happens with probability $\frac{b}{a+b}$. We now would like to calculate the expected number of additional black balls that follow this. Consider a sequence of $a+(b-1)$ balls, and imagine partitioning the sequence by the white balls. The $b-1$ black balls are now divided into $a+1$ "boxes" per se. The expected (average) number of balls in each box is now simply $\frac{b-1}{a+1}$. See if you can finish from here.


 We can repeat this for the case beginning with white and sum to finish. The expected number of like-colored balls that begin the sequence is: $$ \frac{b}{a+b} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{b-1}{a+1}\right) + \frac{a}{a+b} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{a-1}{b+1}\right) $$ $$= \frac{b}{a+b} \cdot \frac{a+b}{a+1} + \frac{a}{a+b} \cdot \frac{a+b}{b+1} $$ $$= \frac{a}{b+1} + \frac{b}{a+1} = \frac{a(a+1) + b(b+1)}{ab+a+b+1}$$

